# CentOS - Can't change ifcfg file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to change an interface config file in a VM: `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/enp0s3` won't write and `sudo bash -c "echo 'dog' >> ./enp0s3"` fails with "Permission Denied".

I've created a new file `/etc/sysconfig/networks-scripts/enp0s8`, and can change it fine. Both files are owned by root and show the same chmod values, `rw-r--r--`. They don't show a `+` when running `ls` which I think means there are no ACL permissions being applied.

They do have a different selinux user thingy when running `ls -Z`. I've set `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and rebooted. `getenforce` returns `disabled`, but I still can't edit the file.

ADDED:
I also don't see any handles on the file when I run `lsof`.

Comment: Could it be a filesystem corruption?

Comment: I am able to edit it on two related vms, so it seems possible. I'm having trouble determining if there is corruption. My invocations of `xfs_repair -n /dev/sda2` can't find the "superblock" and quit, so idk if that's relevant or if I'm pointing it at the wrong thing. However, my other vms (on which I can edit the file) also have that xfs_repair behavior.